# Find a random number length 1 to 10, using numbers 0 to 9 without repeats

Tags: c, algorithm, random, integer

I am trying to find a random number that has 1 to `max` digits (`max` < 10).

```
srand((int) time(NULL));

answer = ((rand() % max) + 1);
```

BUT:

> 0,...9 is only allowed to be used once.

I have found that waiting for the `rand()` to create such a number by chance takes too long, so I am assuming there must be a way to create a running total where each time a digit is added a comparison is made.

Comment: Why not just randomly generate each of ten digits?

Comment: But how do I make sure that the previous digits are excluded, like in the lottery.

Comment: You said "max digits", but in your example code you imply that the answer must be from 1 to max.  Which is it?  Can _all_ the digits be in the range 0 to 9?  Do you want your result as a string or an `unsigned` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an integer with `n` digits drawn from 0 to 9 with no repeats (your question is hard to interpret), then the following will suffice.

The idea is to put all the digits from 0 to 9 in a hat and then draw them out one by one. Append each to the random integer value you're building.

The hat is an array initially set 0 to 9.

To draw a number when the hat has `k` elements in it, compute a random index `j` in the range `[0..k-1]` and get that element from the array. Then copy the last (`k-1` th) element down to position `j`, which "erases" it.  The remaining unpicked digits are now in [0..k-2], and you can repeat this process until done.

Appending a digit d to an integer value is the same as saying

```
val = 10 * val + d
```

Putting these ideas together, you have the following.  Note this allows 0 in the first position, so the result may actually have one less than n digits when printed with no leading zeros.

```
unsigned random_unrepeated_digits(int n) {
  int i, digits[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
  unsigned val = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int k = 10 - i, j = rand() % k;
    val = 10 * val + digits[j];
    digits[j] = digits[k - 1];
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: I just wrote almost the same code in my answer. I upvoted, but you need to be careful not to start the result with 0, and when n is 10 your unsigned may overflow.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks.  I know these things. In fact I said it allows a 0 in the first place, which he did not rule out.  His question is imprecise. If he actually rules out these things I will fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the each digit one by one. First, get a random integer from `0` to `9`. For instance, if you get `5`, then remove it from the array of all digits:

```
0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9
```

Next get a random integer from `0` to `8`, if you get `8` this time, then the second digit is `9`. Remove it and get the next digit repeatedly.

If you need to get 8 digits for instance, In the end you have only 4 digits left, for instance:

```
3 4 6 9
```

Then get a random integer from `0` to `3`. If for instance, you get `0`, then the last digit is `3` and the rest is discarded.

Comment: 1. This doesn't offer an explanation for making the number a random size (number of digits).  and 2. This method would allow a number such as `0453` to be generated, which probably should not be allowed (leading zero).

Comment: A leading zero would be legal. The explanation is great, however, I am struggling to code that.

Comment: @nhgrif I'm using 8 digits as an example only, it's easy to change it to a random number `max`.

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the digits {0, 1, 2, ..., 9}, being careful not to put 0 first, then construct the number from the appropriate number of initial digits. By doing this, while constructing the result as you go, and stopping shuffling once you've fixed the first `ndig` digits, you end up with code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long long rand_digits(int ndig) {
    int digits[10] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    long long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ndig; i++) {
        int r = i + rand() % (10 - i - (i == 0));
        res = res * 10 + digits[r];
        digits[r] = digits[i];
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%-2d: %lld\n", i + 1, rand_digits(i + 1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a function:

```
char * randstr(int len)
{
     srand(0); //seed the generator
     char * str = malloc(len); //allocate exactly len bytes
     int i, x; //define some loop variables
     char used = 0; //used is to check if the number has already been taken
     char num; //a temp value
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
     { //this loop runs through each character in the string
          used = 1;
          while (used) //basically, if we already used it, find another
          {
               used = 0;
               num = rand() % 10 + 48; //48 = '8' //returns 0-9
               for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
               { //this loop checks to see if its already been used
                    if (str[x] == num) used = 1;
               }
           }
     }
     return str;
}
```

This will return a char array, but not a null terminated one, though all of the numbers will be in ASCII form. For a null terminated string, simply modify it like so:

```
char * randstr(int len)
{
     srand(0);
     char * str = malloc(len + 1);
     int i, x;
     char used = 0;
     char num;
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {
          used = 1;
          while (used)
          {
               used = 0;
               num = rand() % 10 + 48; //48 = '8'
               for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
               {
                    if (str[x] == num) used = 1;
               }
           }
     }
     str[len - 1] = 0;
     return str;
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
The way the function works, is it returns a string of size len, using only digits 1-9, with no repeats.

calling randstr(5) could return something like

```
12345
93751
73485
...
```

Do note, if there are no more numbers to use, the function will just sit there looping.
Comments are in the first function

Getting a random number of digits would be actually pretty simple. We just want a random number between 1 and 10. Done by

```
rand() % 10 + 1;


//so lets assign that to an int and call our function
int num = rand() % 10 + 1;
char * str = randstr(num); //assume this is the null terminated one
printf("The number was %s\n", str);
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't offer an explanation for making the number a random size (number of digits). and 2. This method would allow a number such as 0453 to be generated, which probably should not be allowed (leading zero).

Comment: The question asked for numbers between 0-9.  Your solution only provides numbers between 1-9.  And you still don't provide explanation on how to get a random number of digits (although I know how, the explanation isn't given in the answer).

Comment: Why don't you help me out a little then.. I do know of a way, but my coding usually tends to be terribly inefficient

Comment: In a comment to another answer, the quesiton-asker said leading zeros would be fine, so change your code to include 0s, and add the explanation for how to generate a random number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of 10 digits, shuffle them each time and get the N first digits. Pseudo code:

```
void shuffle(char[] a) {
    for(int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
        pos = rand() % 10;
        swap(a[i], a[pos]);
    }
}
int main() {
    char arr[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    # it prints endlessly random numbers of random length
    while (1) {
        shuffle(arr);
        int N = rand() % 10 + 1; # how many digits to generate
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            printf(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The possible issue in this way is when '0' comes the first digit, turning the number to gets less number than it is required. But you can add avoiding '0' at first position by fixing 'shuffle'(e.g, check if the first is '0' then generate random pos=rand()%9+1 and then swap(a[0], a[pos]) or getting numbers if you need it.

Comment: Your shuffle isn't uniform. Check out the wikipedia page on the "Fisher-Yates shuffle".

Comment: I agree - shuffle function should be improved. Thanks for the link